# Как скопировать сообщение пользователя в телеграмме с помощью бота и ввести его в базу данных

Tags: python, aiogram

я являюсь начинающим, и балуюсь с базой данных, возник вопрос. Использую модуль sqlite3, и aiogram. Возник вопрос, как взять следующее сообщение пользователя, и засунуть его в базу данных? Какими методами, можно прибегнуть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала вам стоило бы для начала хоть немного разобраться в теме, благо интернет ещё не запретили.

Насчёт конкретики.

Если вам нужно получить сообщение вам нужен хендлер который это сообщение ловит. После того как вы словили его вы обращаетесь к сообщению и потом переводите его в json и как строку закидывает в бд.

```
from aiogram import types
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(msg: types.Message):
    json_msg = msg.to_json()
```

Запись строк в бд, не сложно сделать и я уверен вы сможете сделать это в течении 10-15 минут. Достаточно запроса в Гугл "как записать данные в бд sqlite".

Comment: Вопрос, как включать эхо запрос когда это будет нужно мне?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Я имею в виду, то что после нажатие определенной кнопки, следующее сообщение должен взять бот. Но у меня получилось так что, он берёт все сообщение от пользователя.

Comment: То есть у вас срабатывает только один хендлер? Или как? Что значит "следующее сообщение должен взять бот"? То что бот что-то напишет? Или мы все же говорим о хендлерах?

Comment: Взять следующее сообщение пользователя, хендлеров у меня используются куча, но сам echo хендлер не работает.

Comment: Я думаю вам нужен FSM для такого

Comment: Да и чтобы нормально помочь нужен код. Просто создайте новый вопрос смысла тут в комментариях тыкать пальцем в небо нет